# Problem, beamer, itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm doing a presentation with beamer documentclass. When I use

```
\documentclass[c,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{helvet}               
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}     
\usepackage{multicol}               
\usepackage{graphicx, fancybox}   
\usepackage{psfrag}                
\usepackage{fancyvrb}             
\usepackage{bbding} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Something1
  \item Something2
\end{frame}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I receive a blank 2 slides. Where could be the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

You have `\end{itemize}` after `\end{frame}`. Put it before.

```
\documentclass[c,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx, fancybox}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Something1
  \item Something2
\end{itemize}    %%% <-- here
\end{frame}
```

[image]